# Factorial of a given number using sequential program

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to this python coding.So,please can someone find what is the problem with this code.

```
def factorial(n):
    sum=1
    for i in range(1..n+1):
        sum=sum*i
    print(sum)
    return sum

v=int(input("enter the number:"))
factorial(v)
```

the error i get:

```
enter the number:4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Ramakrishnar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/fact.py",line 9, in <module>
 factorial(v)
  File "C:/Users/Ramakrishnar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/fact.py", line 3, in factorial
for i in range(1..n+1):
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Comment: for i in range(1, n+1):

Comment: Great, Good luck :)

Comment: I'm curious if you even bothered to look at the documentation for the range command?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can write your program. To reformat your code so that it is in good form, you might organize your program like so:

```
def main():
    variable = int(input('Enter the number: '))
    print(factorial(variable))


def factorial(number):
    total = 1
    for integer in range(1, number + 1):
        total *= integer
    return total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If instead you are trying to accomplish the same thing using the least amount of code, the following two lines will do the exact same thing for you:

```
import math
print(math.factorial(int(input('Enter the number: '))))
```